# Kubernetes windows agent

Tags: windows, azure, kubernetes, agent, azure-container-service

Hey I'm running a Kubernetes cluster on Azure using ACS. 
My question is if there is any way to add a Windows agent to the cluster without completely rebuilding the cluster?

I know this is possible for Linux distro's depending on what you use but I wonder if anyone knows a way to do this for Windows agents?

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your cluster using the Azure portal then you can simply follow the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-scale

But if you have deployed using the ACS engine and ARM template then currently there is an issue that it does not creates the acs resource.